# Cassandra: converting integer to decimal value using cast function error

Tags: cassandra, cql

I am trying to get the average of a column and I want the output to be in decimal format. The column in question is called `rating_place` and it is of type `int`.

Sample data in column `rating_place` is `5, 1, 6, 2, 6, 6, 3, 8, 9, 4` .

This is my code:

```
CREATE INDEX ON place_ratings (place_name);

SELECT CAST(avg(rating_place) AS float) FROM place_ratings WHERE place_name = 'Taco Bills';
```

When I run this code it returns the value 8, but it should be 8.25. What changes do I need to make to my code to get the output in decimal form and not integer form?

Thanks.

Comment: SELECT avg(cast(rating_place as float))  FROM place_ratings WHERE place_name = 'Taco Bills';